# Installation of twitter SDK using fabric Kit : Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter, twitter-fabric

I had went through many surfing and finally I got Fabric Kit for sign in using Twitter in the app. As I had followed the steps provided by fabric but when I click on install button in front of Twitter on fabric then I am getting

[image]

. Please help me to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have fabric account ?

Comment: yes. I have created my account in fabric.

Comment: if it is fine then wait...

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa gg. You tried to contact them?

Comment: Yes, I had also done that and I got this in reply
It’s great to hear from you. We’ve received your email and will get back to you as soon as possible. Our standard support hours are 9am to 5pm ET Monday-Friday.